# MySql table with Foreign key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I cannot set the primary key for the invoice_2 table because it gives an error
here is my code. invoice_1 is the other table that contains the foreign key of the invoice_2 table

`CREATE TABLE invoice_2
(
itemID VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY ,
invoiceNumber INT,FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES invoice_1.invoiceNumber,
quantity INT,
sellingPrice REAL,
lineTotal REAL
)`

Comment: need a help please :)

Comment: many people to vote down the others' posts

Comment: The correct syntax is documented in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE invoice_2
( 
itemID VARCHAR(20),
invoiceNumber INT,
quantity INT, 
sellingPrice REAL,
lineTotal REAL,
PRIMARY KEY (itemID),
CONSTRAINT `FK_invoiceNumber` FOREIGN KEY (`invoiceNumber`) REFERENCES `invoice_1` (`invoiceNumber`)
 );
```

Comment: what is FK_invoiceNumber you are mentioning here?

Comment: It is just foreign key name you can skip it if don't want but this practice is good to distinguish different foreign keys I used as standard FK_Child_table_Name_ColumnName but here only FK_ColName...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the mysql syntax for creating tables and setting PK

`CREATE TABLE table_name
( 
column1 column_definition,
column2 column_definition,
...
CONSTRAINT [constraint_name]
PRIMARY KEY [ USING BTREE | HASH ] (column1, column2, ... column_n));`

TRY: adding a pk constraint

`CREATE TABLE invoice_2( 
itemID VARCHAR(20),
invoiceNumber INT,FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES invoice_1.invoiceNumber,
quantity INT,
sellingPrice REAL,
lineTotal REAL
  CONSTRAINT itemID PRIMARY KEY (itemID)
);`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, it is the name of the constraint.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'references invoice_1.invoiceNumber,
quantity int,
sellingPrice real,
lineTo' at line 4

Comment: @Zafar malik see the answer.